# Transparent shadow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, png, transparent, shadow

I have page with fixed 1000px. I want to set shadow on left and right sides of main page. I can't use static .png with y-repeat, because my background is not a fixed color, it is image. So I can't use image. Any jQuery plugin which can do shadow? Or other solutions, not only jQuery plugins...

Comment: If you were willing to throw ie6 out, you could use a transparent png

Comment: Actually, you don't have to throw out ie6 ... you can use png8 see: http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/03/transparent-pngs-can-deadlock-ie6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* use a transparent `.png` if you use a `png-8` rather than a `png-32`.

Note: It will not give you alpha transparency (you'll have a thin line of your shadow color rather than a gradient) but it lets you approximate the look of your site in IE6 while requiring **no** hacks and **no** IE specific content.

**See:** http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/03/transparent-pngs-can-deadlock-ie6.html

If you want a Jquery plugin to do shadows without `png`s, then Jquery's [Drop Shadow](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropShadow) plugin is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: No CSS/HTML solution is good, I will save shadow image in photoshop as png-8. I before use png-24. The problem only was gradient.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pair of screened divs you could position them and set the z-index above the background, then apply an image to that.